# How to fetch api from the function which pushes each api in array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, fetch-api

I am trying to get API data so i can render it on Webpage using ReactJS. I tried many different ways to fetch api where its stored in array. But i am unable to do it.

Note:`https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/workers/<worker_id>` Here i'm looping so the
worker id gets add the of url.

```
const fetchAPI = e => {
    let array = [];
    const api2 = `https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/workers/`;

    for (var i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
      array.push(api2 + i);
    }
    return array;
  };
  console.log(fetchAPI());
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "unable to do it"? What output are you expecting, what are you getting, and are there errors? Can you provide a [mcve]? This code doesn't show any actual API calls, just strings being pushed onto an array. Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen Okay! So i want to call api using the array which contains the url string.

Comment: Did you try calling `fetch(yourUrlString)`?

Comment: Take a look at `Promise.all` for working with an array of asynchronous stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) for example:

```js
const baseURL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

const fetchUsers = fetch(`${baseURL}/users`);
const fetchPosts = fetch(`${baseURL}/posts`);

Promise.all([fetchUsers, fetchPosts]).then((responses) => {
  const responsesToJson = responses.map(response => response.json());
  
  return Promise.all(responsesToJson);
}).then((jsonResponse) => {
  const [userResponse, postResponse] = jsonResponse;
  
  console.log(userResponse);
  console.log(postResponse);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to hit the url first. Async/Await would be a good choice.

```
<script>
  async function check()
  {
    var arrayData =[];
    var url = "https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/workers/";
    for(var i=1;i<=4;i++)
    {          
      const response = await fetch(url+""+i);
      const myJson = await response.json();
      arrayData.push(myJson);
    }
    console.log(arrayData)

  }
  check();
</script>
```

Comment: It say `arrayData.push(myJson);` myJson is not defined

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake. Can you check now.